# Does a Google Calendar Reminder that's marked as all day give out notification?

Tags: google-calendar, google-calendar-reminders

I set a reminder on my Google Calendar App and set it as all day, but I never received a notification on my phone. Is that suppose to happen?

Comment: Did you find a way to do this? I'd like to know how to get notifications for all-day reminders.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have not. What I do now is that I set it to a specific time when I think it would be useful.

Answer (score 7):

This is the expected behavior per the Google Help Article "[Create & change reminders in Google Calendar](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/6285327?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en)" which states the following:

You'll only get notifications for reminders that are scheduled for a specific time. If you created an all-day reminder, you won't get a notification for it.

Comment: that feature is odd - I would expect all reminders to generate notifications

Comment: In Google Calendar there is also a default time before the meeting that the notification goes out. For example, mine is set to 10 minutes. Since all-day events start at the beginning of the 24 hour period, which would be midnight, sending notifications for all-day events would result in notifications a little before midnight, when most people are asleep. The behavior of not sending notifications for all-day events is very practical.

Comment: @Folk "The behavior of not sending notifications for all-day events is very practical" What is your reasoning behind this statement, besides what you said above? It seems to me as though a *reminder* on *any* platform is utterly freaking useless if it doesn't actually remind you!! So what is the point of these "all-day" reminders?!

Comment: @Kenny83 Why would I need more reasoning than what I said above? As I stated, "sending notifications for all-day events would result in notifications a little before midnight". Most people are asleep at that time of day, so receiving a notification a little before midnight would be annoying, not useful. The point of "all-day" reminders is to allow someone to keep track of, or make note of, an event that occurs on that day (perhaps yearly like a birthday) when they don't need to tie it to a certain time of day.

Comment: @Folk If I don't need to receive a notification, I would use an "event" instead (or "task" for things that don't repeat). On the other hand, when I use a REMINDER, I **do need** to be REMINDED; it's what the name suggests. And yes, there are countless situations where an event doesn't need to be tied to a certain time of day but one needs to be reminded of it. Not all people check the calendar app every day. I rely on notifications for most items, and that's why I mostly use reminders.

Comment: @Folk I agree with you on the point of reminders just before midnight being annoying, not helpful (I would be out for some Google dev's blood if I got woken up at that time for something I didn't want to be reminded about), but my point is that **because** you are right about that, the whole "all-day" feature is useless IMHO. To a newb like me, it seems counter-intuitive to create a **reminder** that doesn't actually **remind** you...anyway since my initial comment was made almost 1.5 years ago, I now know how to use Google Calendar more efficiently for my purposes. Thanks for your input :-)